# Can I have a WHERE condition at the top level of an arbitrary number of joins?

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a table in my database that looks vaguely like this:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  group_id BIGINT,
  type VARCHAR(255)
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
);
```

In other words, a hierarchy of locations. Each location is either a group (`type = 'group'`) or a regular location (`type IS NULL`). Both groups and regular locations can belong to a "parent" group, referenced by `group_id`. Only groups may serve as a parent; regular locations cannot. So, given these records:

```
INSERT INTO locations (id, name, group_id, type) VALUES
  (1, 'Top-level 1', NULL, 'group'),
  (2, 'Mid-level', 1, 'group'),
  (3, 'Location 1', 2, NULL),
  (4, 'Location 2', 2, NULL),
  (5, 'Location 3', 1, NULL),
  (6, 'Top-level 2', NULL, 'group'),
  (7, 'Location 4', 6, NULL);
```

I'd like to query for locations that have "Top-level 1" *anywhere* in their parent chain. Record IDs 3, 4, and 5 should be returned; 7 should not.

If this were just a single optional parent, this would be easy: a single `INNER JOIN`. The problem I'm facing is that the structure can have an *arbitrary* number of parents: this example has two levels of parents, but it could be anything. I also need the solution to work with non-top-level parents - if I queried instead for locations with "Mid-level" in their parent chain, that also needs to work.

I'm sort of expecting the answer to be no - or at least certainly not with JOINs and WHEREs - but is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Mansging hierarchical data in MySQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Without knowing how many nodes per child, that's easier to do in MySql 8 or MariaDb 10. [Old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/4003419)

Comment: @LukStorms `select version()` says I'm on 5.7 right now, but I may well be able to upgrade it. If you want to add that comment as an answer, I'll throw it an upvote at least

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks, but I'll pass. :) A suggestion to upgrade is not a good answer anyway. But I do believe that the [Adjacency List](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) Model is kinda a bad fit for MySql 5.x.  Sure, if you know the maximum node depth is fixed, then you could use the same number of left joins as that max depth. But that won't be pretty.

Comment: @LukStorms Aye, agreed. That, unfortunately, I can't change, so one way or another I have to work with it.

Comment: Example test [here](https://rextester.com/PSDK22697), which assumes that there are maximum 3 levels of child-parent.